# Extract lines between two patterns when there are multiple matches in the file

Tags: regex, sed, awk, grep

I want to extract lines between two patterns (say, pattern1 and pattern2). The structure of the file is the following:

```
a random number of lines containing other stuff
pattern1
some lines to be extracted (finding out the number of lines possible, if necessary)
pattern2
a random number of lines containing other stuff
pattern1
some lines to be extracted
pattern2
a random number of lines containing other stuff
```

This repeats for a large number of times (i.e. there is a large number of matching pattern1-pattern2 pairs). I want to extract the lines between the patterns for all matches, effectively discarding the random stuff.

How can I do this?

Comment: This answer might also be applicable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48022994/2026975

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`

```
awk '/pattern1/,/pattern2/'
pattern1
some lines to be extracted (finding out the number of lines possible, if necessary)
pattern2
pattern1
some lines to be extracted
pattern2
```

---

Only lines between pattern

```
awk '/pattern2/ {f=0;next} f; /pattern1/ {f=1}'
some lines to be extracted (finding out the number of lines possible, if necessary)
some lines to be extracted
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -n "/pattern1/,/pattern2/ {
 /pattern1/ !{
   /pattern2/ !p
   }
 }" InputFile
```

printing line BETWEEN pattern, excluding the patterns itself

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` for this:

```
cat inputfile | sed -ne '/pattern1/,/pattern2/p'
```

Comment: [UUOC](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html)

Comment: just to show you can pipe the command.. but thnx for the award

Answer (score 1):

Here are two more in awk:

```
/pattern1/ {inside_block=1}
/pattern2/ {inside_block=0}
inside_block==1 {print $0}
```

OR

```
/pattern1 { print $0; while(getline > 0) {print $0;if (/pattern2/) break }}
```

Neither is as elegant as the posted solution, but both might be useful depending on other requirements of the program, or the complexity of the pattern.

Comment: First example prints start pattern `pattern1` line and text to extract, but not stop pattern `pattern2`. Either none, or both.  Second does not work, due to missing "\" after `pattern1`.