# A grep (or sed, or awk) command to select all lines that follow a specific pattern after a specific start line in a file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, yaml

In the `yml` files of `Docker Compose`, the volumes are declared in a section that starts with `volumes:` line and followed by patterns such as `- host/dir:guest:dir`. The sesction ends with the start of the next section, which its name would not be the same all the time, and it could be any of `ports:`, `environment:`, and `networks:`, among others. There is usually more than one `volumes:` section, and the number of lines in each of those is not known (and is not constant across the `volumes:` sections).

I need to extract all the volume declarations (i.e., `- host/dir:guest:dir`) from all `volumes:` sections of a `yml` file.

Thanks!

An example `yml` file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  service1:
    image: repo1/image1
    volumes:
      - /dir1/dir2:/dir3/dir4
      - /dir5/dir6:/dir7/dir8
    ports:
      - "80:80"
  service2:
    image: repo2/image2
    volumes:
      - /dir9/dir10:/dir11/dir12
    environment:
      - A: B
```

Comment: Parse a `yaml` with regex, not a great idea. Python has a `yaml` module to work with

Comment: Thanks @Inian. I need a `bash` one-liner solution.

Comment: well if you feel regex can solve this problem, then do add your own efforts to question.. and add expected output for clarity..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**awk** one-liner

Assuming you have `/` in each volume declaration

**Input** :

```
version: '2'
services:
  service1:
    image: repo1/image1
    volumes:
      - /dir1/dir2:/dir3/dir4
      - /dir5/dir6:/dir7/dir8
    ports:
      - "80:80"
  service2:
    image: repo2/image2
    volumes:
      - /dir9/dir10:/dir11/dir12
    environment:
      - A: B
    volumes:
      - /dir1/dir2:/dir3/dir4
      - /dir5/dir6:/dir7/dir8
meow:
```

**Output**:

```
$awk '$0!~"/"{a=0}  /volumes:/{a=1; next}a' file
      - /dir1/dir2:/dir3/dir4
      - /dir5/dir6:/dir7/dir8
      - /dir9/dir10:/dir11/dir12
      - /dir1/dir2:/dir3/dir4
      - /dir5/dir6:/dir7/dir8
```

`$0!~"/"{a=0}` : If the record/line doesn't contain `/` that means it's not a volume declaration ; set `a=0`
`/volumes:/{a=1; next}` : If the line contains `volumes:` then set `a=1` and `next` i.e jump to next record
`a` : To print the records if `a=1`

PS : If in your yml file a tag containing `/` can come just after volumes then this can fail. If that's the case then use this awk :

```
$awk '$1!~"-"{a=0}  /volumes:/{a=1; next}a' file
```

This will reset `a` if first field isn't `-`

Comment: Thanks! I have to add awk to the title of the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$1=="-"{if (f) print; next} {f=/^[[:space:]]*volumes:/}' file
```

Comment: Thanks! The case of an empty `volumes:` section should be rare but it could happen.

Comment: The script would handle it just fine if it did happen, it will robustly/reliably print the declarations within every `volumes:` section, no more and no less.

Comment: I meant to say the same thing. Thank.